# UFT/QTP recording error

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp

Just started with HP UFT software. 
Started new project/test and clicked on GUI test. Then, when I click on RECORD i get this error. Tried to look for solution online but can't find anything.
[image: error]

[image: error details]

Comment: This looks like a bug, I would try to reinstall UFT and if that doesn't solve the issue contact HPE's support.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Additional Installation Requirements AS ADMIN:

- Go to Start>All Programs>HP Software>HP Unified Functional
  Testing>Tools>Additional Installation Requirements.
- RIGHT click on 'Additional Installation Requirements' and click 'Run as
  Administrator'.
- Uncheck 'Run License Installation Wizard' and "Run
  The Terminal Emulation wizard" (if present) but check everything
  else.
- Click RUN.